# Error in R apply() function with lubridate

Tags: r

I have a simple function like this:

```
f<-function(x){ ymd_h(x[1]) + (x[2] )}
```

Here I use `ymd_h(), hours()` from the `lubridate` package. But when I try to call this function from `apply` method like this:

```
result<-apply(wind.new[,c("date","hors")],1,f)
```

... where `*wind.new` is a data frame with `date`, `hors` and other columns,
I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : could not find function "ymd_h"
```

Obviously `ymd_h` is not visible inside `apply()`. How would I fix this?
UPDATE:
 Actually I have the data frame showed below and want to convert **date** column to YYYYMMDDHH format and add **hors** column to it as hours. I thought the best approach will be to use lubridate package and I used above mentioned function for that. But the execution took very long time and the output was not correct. Any hints, please?

```
   date    hors   u      v        ws    wd
2009070100  1   2.34    -0.79   2.47    108.68
2009070100  2   2.18    -0.99   2.4     114.31
2009070100  3   2.2     -1.21   2.51    118.71
............
2009070100  47  2.3     -2.18   3.17    133.5
2009070100  48  1.93    -1.87   2.69    134.12
2009070112  1   2.77    -0.65   2.85    103.17
```

.........

Comment: Did you call `require(lubridate)` in this R session?

Comment: No, I didn't :-(. Sorry for so simple question. The command worked after adding `require(lubridate)` But I didn't get the expected result after the execution and it took too long time

Comment: My answer works with your example data

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that @DrewSteen's comment regarding loading the lubridate package onto the search path is correct.

I think you will have issues with your function because `apply` will coerce to matrix and will return the incorrect type (more coercions required)

Changing your function to take the date-time and hours data as separate arguments should help.

```
library(lubridate)
f <- function(date, hours){ymd_h(date) + hours(hours)}

result <- with(wind.new, f(as.character(date), hors))
```

`ymd_h` will be slow as it has to guess the format of the date/time.